# Calling service returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a service called `ActiveUserProfileService`, but when I call its function in a controller I get `undefined` as a result and I cannot figure out why. The strangest part is that, in the `ActiveUserProfileService` service, the information from the UserService is displayed through `console.log`, so I'm receiving the information, but after calling the `ActiveUserProfileService` in the controller, it gives me `undifened`. It seems like the data isn't passed around. Can someone help me ?

UserService.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {
            getAuthenticatedUser:         getAuthenticatedUser,
            getUserInformation:           getUserInformation

        };
        return service;

        function getUserInformation(idUser) {
            return $http.post('api/user/details', {idUser: idUser});
        }
        function getAuthenticatedUser() {
            return $http.get('api/user');
        }

    }

})();
```

ActiveUserProfileService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('ActiveUserProfileService', ActiveUserProfileService);

    ActiveUserProfileService.$inject = ['$http','UserService'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ActiveUserProfileService($http, UserService) {


        var service = {
            isAccount:            isAccount
        };
        return service;

        ////////////////

        function isAccount(accountName) {
            UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;

                    UserService.getUserInformation(data.user.id)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            var userDetails = response.data;
                            console.log("It is");
                            console.log(accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal);

                            return  accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal;
                        });
                })
        }

    }

})();
```

My controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('WizardController', WizardController);

    WizardController.$inject = [
        'UserService',

        'ActiveUserProfileService'

    ];

    /* @ngInject */
    function WizardController(UserService,ActiveUserProfileService) {

        var vm = this;


       console.log("ActiveUserProfileService");
    console.log(ActiveUserProfileService.isAccount("professional")); //is Returning me undefined



    }

})
();
```

Comment: You see your callback? It's assuming return, then it's not the main function return but the callback instead. You must create a promise that will be resolved as your callback is called, then you return this promise

Comment: We lack information about how it is used in your controller, would you mind pasting your controller here ? Does calling your UserService works inside your controller ?

Comment: Yes it works. and i already edit the controller

Comment: Thank you. LanaStf answered your question brillantly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is, you're trying to return a value for isAccount inside another function, a callback. When you do that, you're returning a value to this function, and not isAccount itself, so isAccount will not return anything, undefined, then.
As you are calling an assynchronous method, then isAccount must be assynchronous as well,

Replace

```
 function isAccount(accountName) {
        UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;

                UserService.getUserInformation(data.user.id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        var userDetails = response.data;
                        console.log("It is");
                        console.log(accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal);

                        return  accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal;
                    });
            })
    }
```

with

```
 function isAccount(accountName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                //when the user is loaded, then you resolve the promise you has already returned
                UserService.getUserInformation(data.user.id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        var userDetails = response.data;
                        console.log("It is");
                        console.log(accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal);
                        deferred.resolve(accountName == userDetails.account_types[0].description_internal);
                        return; //here is not isAccount return, but anonymous inner function 'function (response)', you got it?
                    });
            });
    return deferred.promise; //return as soon as creates the promise
}
```

For sure you'd have to inject $q service as well

Comment: Thanks Lana, is working, just one question is returning me 'c {$$state: Object}' in the controller.

Comment: You're welcome.Well, it is a promise, just like getAuthenticatedUser returns one. So you can use isAccount().then(yourCallBackWithBooleanHere);

Comment: But is it possible returning from the isAccount the value whiout "then..", im telling this because in the controller i inserted `code` vm.isAccount = function(account) {
            
           ActiveUserProfileService.isAccount(account).then(
                function (result) {
                    return result;

                }
            );
        };`code` And than i made this function being called in a view from the ngIf, but is giving me a "error $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop"

Comment: You're doing the same error again, buddy. Look at vm.isAccount return, it ain't returning anything, right? inner return statement is being used for the callback, not the main function vm.isAccount. O retorno não está servindo para o método isAccount, mas para a callback passada dentro do then, ou seja, o método isAccount não está retornando nada